# When I click on Sign in with Google button nothing happens

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I wanted to implement Firebase authentication via Google authentication. Thus, I used this code:

> import firebase from 'firebase/app';
>       import 'firebase/firestore';
>       import 'firebase/auth';
>
> ```
> const config = {
>   apiKey: "REDACTED",
>   authDomain: "crwn-33842.firebaseapp.com",
>   databaseURL: "https://crwn-33842.firebaseio.com",
>   projectId: "crwn-33842",
>   storageBucket: "crwn-33842.appspot.com",
>   messagingSenderId: "479080549871",
>   appId: "1:479080549871:web:1b08546056e621651eba1a"
> }
>
> firebase.initializeApp(config);
>
> export const auth = firebase.auth();
> export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
> const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
> provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt:'select_account' })
> export const signInGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup();
>
> export default firebase;   Also have this component code:
>
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> import FormInput from './../form-input.component/form-input.component';
> import CustomButton from './../CustomButton/customButton.component';
> import { signInGoogle } from './../../firebase/firebase.utils';
>
> class SignIn extends Component {
>   state = { 
>     login:'',
>     password: '',
>   }
>
>   handleChange = event =>{
>     const {name, value} = event.target;
>
>     this.setState({ [name]: value });
>   }
>
>   handleSubmit = event =>{
>     event.preventDefault();
>
>     this.setState({ login:'', password:'' })
>   }
>
>   render() { 
>     return ( 
>       <div>
>         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
>           <FormInput
>             handleChange={this.handleChange}
>             value={this.state.login}
>             name='login'
>             label='Login'
>             required
>           />
>           <FormInput
>             handleChange={this.handleChange}
>             value={this.state.password}
>             name='password'
>             label='Password'
>             required
>           />
>           <CustomButton type='submit' label='Sign In'/>
>           <CustomButton onClick={signInGoogle} label='Sign In with Google'/>
>         </form>
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> export default SignIn;
> ```

So, when I click on

> `<CustomButton onClick={signInGoogle} label='Sign In with Google'/>`

I get [![enter image description here][1]][1]

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeGr7.png

Comment: can you check if popup is blocked in the browser

Comment: Wrap it inside a try-catch and then share the error here. Btw, you should not share your App-secrets publically.

Comment: @AnurodhSingh, I added the error I get

Comment: @Vidit, I edited my question and I added the error I get

Comment: Please post/share errors as text not images. Text is searchable, text in images is not. Also please edit your code to be a code snippet and not a quote for readability. I already did it once to improve readability and remove your api-key, but it seems you copy/pasted over it when updating to add error.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `provider` in the `auth.signInWithPopup()` method.

The `signInWithPopup` method must like this,

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

Modify the calling of `signInWithPopup` line with the below line in your code,

```
export const signInGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

For reference, go to this link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk

Answer (score 0):

`signInWithPopup` method accepts an argument `provider`

This is the modified code

```
const config = {
  apiKey: "REDACTED",
  authDomain: "crwn-33842.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://crwn-33842.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "crwn-33842",
  storageBucket: "crwn-33842.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "479080549871",
  appId: "1:479080549871:web:1b08546056e621651eba1a"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt:'select_account' })
export const signInGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;   Also have this component code:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormInput from './../form-input.component/form-input.component';
import CustomButton from './../CustomButton/customButton.component';
import { signInGoogle } from './../../firebase/firebase.utils';

class SignIn extends Component {
  state = { 
    login:'',
    password: '',
  }

  handleChange = event =>{
    const {name, value} = event.target;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event =>{
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ login:'', password:'' })
  }

  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.login}
            name='login'
            label='Login'
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.password}
            name='password'
            label='Password'
            required
          />
          <CustomButton type='submit' label='Sign In'/>
          <CustomButton onClick={signInGoogle} label='Sign In with Google'/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```